# Matt Parker mistake in cannonball stacking video

Tags: programming, popular-math

I could need someone to do a check on this problem, since it has been published in Matt Parkers book "things to make and do in the fourth dimension" and has now been featured in a numberphile video

In Matt Parker's most [recent video on numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6L06pyt9CA&t=230s) he states that you can build a giant hexagon with sides of length 22 and it will take 946 balls. It looks like he has used [these numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_number) when he in reality should have been using [these](https://oeis.org/A003215) so he got the layers to be $1,6,15,\ldots,946$ instead of $1,7,19,\ldots,1387$.

The problem he was trying to solve was if there exists a number of cannonballs where they can both form a flat hexagon and a hexagonal pyramid (inspired by this [old problem](https://www.pedagonet.com/mathgenius/test138.html)).

I made a simple python programme to check for a solution of the height up to $10^7$ (which equals $10^{18}$ cannonballs) with no solution

```
layer_size = 1
sum_to_height = 1
totals = []
layers = []
for height in range(2,10000):
    layer_size = 3*((height-1)**2+height-1)+1 #Formula for how many balls in each layer
    sum_to_height += layer_size   #Sum of all balls in pyramid to current height
    totals.append(sum_to_height)
    layers.append(layer_size)

print(set(layers).intersection(totals)) #If there is a intersect, then that is a solution
```

Comment: I believe he is using the wrong sequence based off the problem he is trying to solve

Comment: So that is your opinion. What is your question?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the video it is clear that he really meant hexagonal numbers [OEIS A000384](https://oeis.org/A00384), where $A000384(22) = 946$ and the sum of the first $11$ of these is also $946$. You are using a closely related but different sequence [OEIS A003215](https://oeis.org/A003215) which is **centered** hexagonal numbers. The hexagonal array of balls look very superficially the same, but only the centered version has a center with six triangles radiating outwards. The version used in the video has four triangles radiating from a single vertex of the hexagon.